# binding in xaml, xaml parse exception

Tags: .net, xaml, xamlparseexception

I am currently using the WPF .NET 3.5 for the development, using the ikriv's Math Converter, I decided to do a mathematical task in my design:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RectangleTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Shape" Stroke="#d69e31" Fill="{StaticResource YellowGradientBrush}">
            <!-- Create a rectangle that applies Cornering accoding to it's (in form) indicated height -->
            <Rectangle.RadiusX>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MathConverter}" ConverterParameter="x/2.5">
                    <!-- Error occurs in the line below -->
                    <Binding Path="Object" ElementName="{TemplateBinding Property=Button.Height}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.RadiusX>
            <Rectangle.RadiusY>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MathConverter}" ConverterParameter="x/2.5">
                    <!-- Error occurs in the line below -->
                    <TemplateBinding Property="Button.Height" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.RadiusY>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

+Exception assist says:

InnerException: System.InvalidCastException

Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.TemplateBindingExpression' to type 'System.String'.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is an error in that line. Please give some information about what you want this binding to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an error in that line. Please give some more information about where is the button you refer to in that binding.

If it's the control that you create template for, you can try to remove the line:

```
<!-- this line causes an error -->
<Binding Path="Object" ElementName="{TemplateBinding Property=Button.Height}" />
```

and replace it with a new one:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Height" />
```